# Are all the global variables and global functions members of the `window` object?

Tags: javascript

When using JavaScript in a browser on a webpage,

- are all the global variables and global functions members of the `window` object?
- are all the members of the `window` object  global variables and global functions?

If the answer(s) is no,

- what kinds of   global variables and global functions are  members of the `window` object? What kinds are not?
- what kinds of   members of the `window` object  are global variables and global functions? What kinds are local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are all the global variables and global functions members of the window object?

All global variables declared with `var` and functions (and all variables that are not declared at all (!¹)) are.

> are all the members of the window object global variables and global functions?

Yes. The `window` variable itself is actually just a property of the window object (`undefined` and `NaN` too ... they aren't keywords...).

All the default properties of the window object are

1) [the global object properties according to the ES spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

2) [window specific properties according to the Web spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

---

¹ You should always declare your variables. You should always use `let` / `const` in favor of `var` (because `var name = 12; console.log(typeof name)` surprises you otherwise). And you should `"use strict;"`mode which prevents undeclared variables.

Comment: Thanks. Are global properties `localStorage` and `geolocation` members of the `window` object or members of some other object?

Comment: @tim yes they are.